# Condition in ASP Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to put a condition into my ASP repeater tag. I have a table being created and one of the td items is a link. The problem is I need to create a link upon checking the value in one the variable that is in the repeater container. Here is my code:

```
<td><%#((VWApp.Code.TrackDM)Container.DataItem).CdNo%></td>
<td><%#((VWApp.Code.TrackDM)Container.DataItem).ShippingNo%></td>
```

Now i need to check the value of ShippingNo and rather than displaying it need to display a link. i tried to write an if condition like this:

```
if(((VWApp.Code.TrackDM)Container.DataItem).ShippingNo. .. )
{
// do processing and generate a link that needs to displayed
}
```

But i get error when trying to do this. Can anybody guide me to the right way of doing this?

Any ideas and suggests are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `<asp:Hyperlink>` inside your `<td>`, and bind its `Visible` property to an expression which will check ShippingNo and return true if it represents a valid link.

Comment: But then how will i display shippingNo without link? there are cases where we don't need to display link but the number has to be displayed

Comment: Then you need both a `<asp:Hyperlink>` and a `<asp:Label>`, each of it with `Visible` properties set accordlingly to the value of ShippingNo.

Answer (score 1):

You can always go the old-fashioned route of not using a repeater at all, but rather inline code, where you can use whatever code you need.  Something like:

```
<% foreach (SomeObject obj in MyObjectCollection) { %>
  <td>
    <% if (obj.SomeProperty == something) { %>
      <a href="<%= /* build link */ %>">Click Me</a>
    <% } else { %>
      Some Text
    <% } %>
  </td>
<% } %>
```

It's the classic ASP way of doing things, but I've found it works better for some situations.  Sometimes it's just easier to do things with real code as opposed to working within the boundaries of a Repeater or GridView.

Comment: And it may perform better, CPU wise. Of course it may quickly become a huge mess as the code grows.

Comment: Agreed that it may be a mess, but nothing irritates me more than writing a big GridView with lots of fancy bound controls with string formats, alternate row settings, and other control-specific things, then find one little problem that can't be solved, but would have otherwise been easy with inline code.  (Ok, a lot of things irritate me more than that, but that has happened before and it's a pain to deal with).

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your logic in a [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) and pass it the parameters it needs to makes display decisions:

```
<uc:linkdisplay id="linkdisplay1" runat="server" 
      CdNo='<%#((VWApp.Code.TrackDM)Container.DataItem).CdNo %>' 
      ShippingNo='<%#((VWApp.Code.TrackDM)Container.DataItem).ShippingNo%>' />
```